# Async / Await not working with http request

Tags: javascript

I try to get content with an async call and grab the response via an async function. What is wrong with this setup? The result of the console log is always undefined?

```
_json: function (callback) {
        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xobj.open('GET', this.options.url, true);

        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                callback(xobj.responseText);
            }
        };

        xobj.send(null);
    },

    get: async function () {
        var resp = await this._json(function(response) {
            return JSON.parse(response);
        });

        console.log(resp);
    }
```

Comment: There is 1 simple rule to check whenever you should use `async / await` or not. `Does your function / method returns an promise? If yes, you can use it, if no it makes no sense`. You can apply it for your problem here. Does `this._json()` returns an promise? No, so it does not make sense to use `await` on it. You need to return an promise in order to make it work

Comment: You don't need to use async/await in this case, unless you have a particular reason to (and you have that async function returning a promise). Just console.log the response inside the callback function, without using any async/await.

Comment: use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest` then you can use async / await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `async / await` you need to know when to use `await` in the first place. You cannot just put simply `await` infront of anything and expect that it somehow awaits something.

So, when should you use `await` or lets say when does it make sense to use it?

One simple question:

1. Does your method / function returns an Promise?

   - Yes: You can put `await` infront of it
   - No: Its useless to use `await`

We can make that check on your issue:

Does `this._json()` returns an Promise?

In your case `no`. That means using `await` is useless.

What you can do is returning an promise:

```
  _json: function () {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest()

      xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json')
      xobj.open('GET', this.options.url, true)

      xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status === 200) {
          res(xobj.responseText)
        } else {
          rej('Something went wrong')
        }
      }
      xobj.send(null)
    })
  },

  get: async function () {
    var resp = await this._json()
    console.log(resp)
  },
```

`this._json()` returns an Promise now. In this case it makes sense to use `await`.

Remember: By putting `async` infront of an function,your function then returns also an promise.

Answer (score 2):

Your `_json` function is not a Promise. It uses common callback pattern to pass information back asynchronously. You have to wrap it in a Promise first, if you want to use async/await syntax.

```js
new Promise((resolve) => this._json((response) => resolve(JSON.parse(response)))
```

Then you can `await` it and receive parsed JSON (as you expect).

Comment: ugh that's ugly :D